# Sorting list with repository and ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

First time adding an object (Deck) is added invisibly. It will only appear once the sorting method has been chosen from context menu. However, this has to be repeated each time for the screen to be updated.

The issue should lie within the repository as `getAllDecks` references `allDecks`. It is as if `allDecks` is not updating or not realising its `.value` is changing as `allDecks.postValue()` intakes the `List<Deck>` from database. This isn't a `LiveData<List<Deck>>`, it only does a one time thing. How to make repository reading constant updates from database?

I am trying to sort a list stored in the repository. My ViewModel has a `List<obj>` referencing items in repository. Sorting occurs when a user presses a context menu item. This action isn't working. The debugging tool showed repository method being called and things were reassigned. This should have worked as ViewModel was referencing the repository and MainActivity would automatically update if the list changed.

MainActivity context menu opens and reacts to `onClick` sorting changes. Thus it is called. I also know since delete and insert queries are working that MainActivity is listening to the ViewModel's changing list. What am I doing wrong? Also, how to debug database queries (when debugger transitions to viewing SQLite query it gets in a loop)?

Main Activity (abbreviated) :

```
         globalViewModel.sortBy(Sort.ALPHA_ASC) //Set default sorting

        //Listen for livedata changes in ViewModel. if there is, update recycler view
        globalViewModel.allDecks.observe(this, Observer { deck ->
            deck?.let { adapter.setDecks(deck) }
        })
 override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.sort_by_alpha_asc -> { globalViewModel.sortBy(Sort.ALPHA_ASC) ; currentSort = Sort.ALPHA_ASC ; contextMenuText.setText(R.string.sort_by_alpha_asc) ; return true; }
            R.id.sort_by_alpha_desc -> { globalViewModel.sortBy(Sort.ALPHA_DES) ; currentSort = Sort.ALPHA_DES ; contextMenuText.setText(R.string.sort_by_alpha_des) ; return true; }
            R.id.sort_by_completed_hidden -> { globalViewModel.sortBy(Sort.NON_COM) ; currentSort = Sort.NON_COM ; contextMenuText.setText(R.string.sort_by_non_complete) ; return true; }
            R.id.sort_by_due_date -> { globalViewModel.sortBy(Sort.DUE_DATE) ; currentSort = Sort.DUE_DATE ; contextMenuText.setText(R.string.sort_by_due_date) ; return true; }
            else -> return super.onContextItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

View Model :

```
private val repository: DeckRepository
val allDecks: LiveData<List<Deck>>

init {
    val decksDao = FlashCardDB.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).DeckDAO()
    repository = DeckRepository(deckDao = decksDao)
    allDecks = repository.getAllDecks()
}

fun sortBy(sortMethod: Sort) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    when (sortMethod) {
        Sort.ALPHA_ASC -> repository.sortBy(Sort.ALPHA_ASC)
        Sort.ALPHA_DES -> repository.sortBy(Sort.ALPHA_DES)
        Sort.NON_COM -> repository.sortBy(Sort.NON_COM)
        Sort.DUE_DATE -> repository.sortBy(Sort.DUE_DATE)
    }
}
```

DeckRepository :

```
private var allDecks = MutableLiveData<List<Deck>>() //instantiate object

    fun getAllDecks(): LiveData<List<Deck>> = allDecks //Repository handles livedata transmission. ViewModel references the actual Data.

    suspend fun sortBy(sortingMethod: Sort) {
        when (sortingMethod) {
            Sort.ALPHA_ASC -> allDecks.postValue(deckDao.getDecksSortedByAlphaAsc())
            Sort.ALPHA_DES -> allDecks.postValue(deckDao.getDecksSortedByAlphaDesc())
            Sort.NON_COM -> allDecks.postValue(deckDao.getDecksSortedByNonCompleted())
            Sort.DUE_DATE -> allDecks.postValue(deckDao.getDecksSortedByDueDate())
        }
    }

    suspend fun insert(deck: Deck) {
        deckDao.insert(deck)
    }
```

Database :

```
//Sorting
@Query("SELECT * from deck_table ORDER BY title ASC")
fun getDecksSortedByAlphaAsc(): List<Deck>

@Query("SELECT * from deck_table ORDER BY title DESC")
fun getDecksSortedByAlphaDesc(): List<Deck>

@Query("SELECT * from deck_table WHERE completed=1 ORDER BY title ASC")
fun getDecksSortedByNonCompleted(): List<Deck>

@Query("SELECT * from deck_table ORDER BY date ASC")
fun getDecksSortedByDueDate(): List<Deck>

//Modifying
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
suspend fun insert(deck: Deck)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity isn't showing the changes in real time because your repository reassigns its LiveData. While your approach of having a single LiveData to be observed by the activity is correct, you should actually change only its value, not the reference if that makes sense.

Here's an example:

**Repository**

```
private val allDecks = MutableLiveData<List<Deck>>()

fun getAllDecks(): LiveData<List<Deck>> = allDecks

fun sortBy(sortingMethod: Sort) {
    when (sortingMethod) {
        /* If you're handling your DB operations with coroutines, this function
         * should be suspendable and you should set the value to allDecks
         * with postValue
         */
        Sort.ALPHA_ASC -> allDecks.value = deckDao.getDecksSortedByAlphaAsc()
        Sort.ALPHA_DES -> allDecks.value = deckDao.getDecksSortedByAlphaDesc()
        Sort.NON_COM -> allDecks.value = deckDao.getDecksSortedByNonCompleted()
        Sort.DUE_DATE -> allDecks.value = deckDao.getDecksSortedByDueDate()
    }
}
```

Consequently, your DAO queries will no longer return LiveData, but the lists themselves:

**DAO**

```
@Query("SELECT * from deck_table ORDER BY title ASC")
fun getDecksSortedByAlphaAsc(): List<Deck>


@Query("SELECT * from deck_table ORDER BY title DESC")
fun getDecksSortedByAlphaDesc(): List<Deck>

@Query("SELECT * from deck_table WHERE completed=1 ORDER BY title ASC")
fun getDecksSortedByNonCompleted(): List<Deck>

@Query("SELECT * from deck_table ORDER BY date ASC")
fun getDecksSortedByDueDate(): List<Deck>
```

Comment: Can you confirm if this is correct,
LiveData should not be reassigned as the Activities won't render this change? You change the value of a reference as that reference remains the same so it just reloads it?.
However, shouldn't both of these changes result in the same end result. I am confused why my method wouldnt work. If MainActivity is listening to a change in the ViewModel. Shouldnt the reassigning count as a change

Comment: It may seem like it will work but it won't as you're observing the data belonging to a specific reference of LiveData. When you change the reference (not its value) you will see the change only after you refresh your activity, which takes away the entire point of using LiveData, but if you keep the reference and only change its value, that change will be immediately reflected to all observers

Comment: I understand the theory behind it. However, I spent a bit of time trying to get it running, and it is failing. 
From what I gathered from your example. My MainActivity sets the default sorting method so the allDecks has a reference to the deckDao which is automatically updating.
However, that doesn't seem to be the case as inserting new Decks no longer works. Is this because of the DeckDao now return livedata? but should be updated as per the Repository.

TLDR: I am struggling to implement your example, may I get some assistance

Comment: It's quite late where I am right now but tomorrow I'll update my answer covering all layers from DAO to Activity

Comment: I piggy backed of what you suggested. I got it working by having an observerForever in the MainActivity and used MediatorLiveData which swaps its source when the sort is activated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in DAO's query. It returns List, witch is not Flow or LiveData, thus it can't be observed and react to changes in list... It should be like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * from deck_table ORDER BY title ASC")
fun getDecksSortedByAlphaAsc(): Flow<List<Deck>>

@Query("SELECT * from deck_table ORDER BY title DESC")
fun getDecksSortedByAlphaDesc(): Flow<List<Deck>>

@Query("SELECT * from deck_table WHERE completed=1 ORDER BY title ASC")
fun getDecksSortedByNonCompleted(): Flow<List<Deck>>

@Query("SELECT * from deck_table ORDER BY date ASC")
fun getDecksSortedByDueDate(): Flow<List<Deck>>
```

Now you can iplement allDecks variable witch will be LiveData<List> using flow and Transformations. Something like this:

```
val sortingMethod: LiveData<Sort> = "your sorting type here"

val allDecks: LiveData<List<Deck>> = Transformations.switchMap(sortingMethod) {
       when (sortingMethod) {
        Sort.ALPHA_ASC -> allDecks.value = deckDao.getDecksSortedByAlphaAsc().asLiveData()
        Sort.ALPHA_DES -> allDecks.value = deckDao.getDecksSortedByAlphaDesc().asLiveData()
        Sort.NON_COM -> allDecks.value = deckDao.getDecksSortedByNonCompleted().asLiveData()
        Sort.DUE_DATE -> allDecks.value = deckDao.getDecksSortedByDueDate().asLiveData()
}
```

Whats happens is we observe liveData sorting method and change our allDecks variable every time when it changes.

After this you just need to observe allDecks and submit it to recycler view adapter every time it changes.

Something like this:

```
viewModel.allDecks.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {
    adapter.submitList(it)
}
```

P.S. RecyclerViews adapter must be implemented using DiffCallback so it can change every time list is changed...